# How to create HTML table with jQuery and multiplication rows and columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table, multiplication

I need to create HTML table using jQuery dynamically and also I need to make multiplication between rows and columns. My rows is yield and column is price. I have two variables a and b.

```
var a; //represent price
var b; // represent yield
```

Now I need to create table and multiplication like this:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2" scope="col">Yield</th>
    <th colspan="7" scope="col">Price</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>a-1.5</td>
    <td>a-1</td>
    <td>a-0.5</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>a+0.5</td>
    <td>a+1</td>
    <td>a+1.5</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">b-500</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">b-400</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">b-300</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">b-200</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">b-100</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">b</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>a*b</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">b+100</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">b+200</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">b+300</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">b+400</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th scope="row">b+500</th>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nexetdad/

So columns is based on price +/- and rows are based on yield +/-. How I can create with JavaScript table matrix so every cell need to be calculated (a*b)?

Please give me some ideas. I don't know where to start.

Comment: You should consider using angular.js

Comment: hello, I append my jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are lack of DOM skill.
You can refer it.

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function addlabel(s,n){
     if (n > 0){
         return s + "+" + String(n);
     }
     else if (n < 0){
      return s + String(n);
     }
     else{
      return s;
     }
 }

 function multiplicationTable(){
     x = document.getElementById("i1").value;
     x = parseInt(x);
     y = document.getElementById("i2").value;
     y = parseInt(y);
     var table = '<table border="1px"><thead>';
     table += '<tr><th></th>'
     for (var a = -1.5; a<= 1.5 ; a+=0.5){
         table += '<th>'+ addlabel("a", a) +'</th>';
     }
     table += '</tr></thead><tbody>'

     // add num
     for (var b = y-500, ob = y; b<= y+500 ; b+=100){        
         table += "<tr>";
         table += "<td>" + addlabel("b",b-ob) + "</td>"
         for (var a = x-1.5; a<= x+1.5 ; a+=0.5){
             table += '<td>'+ a*b +'</td>';
         }
         table += "</tr>";
     }
     return table + '</tbody></table>';
 }

 function build(){
     document.getElementById('here').innerHTML = multiplicationTable();
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="f"> 
        <input type="text" value ="15" name="r" id="i1">
        <input type="text" value ="5000" name="c" id="i2">
        <input type="button" value="make table" onclick="build()">
    </form>
    <div id="here">
    </div>
</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tonypythoneer/z5reeomj/2/

Comment: Ok, thanks but where is headers of table here ? I cant review this witout header... so please make this with all elements like I have here: http://jsfiddle.net/nexetdad/

Answer (score 1):

Although i dont know much about js and jquery you can mix them and this could be done. Go for nested for loop for creating your table and use *append()* of jquery for appending the content of table and simple multiplication.

By the way this can done easily using php.

Comment: i assume u are ok with using php. Make 2 nested for loop. 1 for `<tr>` and the other for `<td>` and in `<td>` do your multiplication.